# Draw custom view within UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit

I want to extend `UITextField` to draw inputed text in a custom `UILabel` like class that draws certain symbols in a special way. Would I have to modify the drawing code directly or is there a way to add this view "on top" of the `UITextField` while still being able to input text into the `UITextField`?

Comment: Would it work to create a custom font and use that?

Comment: I doubt it, I'm actually formatting input into LaTeX and rendering that using a library that implements a custom class that functions like a `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

This should add a view to a text field. Now just change thisView to any custom view you want with any custom frame you want and pow! You got what you want ;)

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
let thisView = UIView(frame: frame)
thisView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
textField.addSubview(thisView)
```

Comment: if you use this solution, you probably also need to set textColor of the textField to clearColor.